# Reorder list in python by given index

Tags: python

Is it possible to reorder a list by given index in python ?

If i have the list: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

I would like to reorder by the second index to have something like this: `[3,4,5,1,2]`

Comment: `result = list_[index:]+list_[:index]`

Comment: The other commenters seem to have understood the question better than I have been able to, but if this question is not a simple duplicate, it could certainly do with being clearer.

Comment: This solves the above example `sorted(arr[2:]) + sorted(arr[:2])`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

result = list[:index] + list[index:]

Comment: this is equivalent to the list itself and not a solution.